# Некорректное отображение тем xfce4 на Funtoo Linux

Tags: gtk3, xfce4

**Речь идет про Funtoo Linux 4.8.7-gentoo-kernel и xfce 4.12.1-r1**

После очередной установки Funtoo Linux обозначился неприятный сюрприз - темы устанавливались только для gtk3, часть интерфейса (элементов управления) в плагинах xfce4 рисовалась без элементов управления. Если быть точнее - рисовался только текст. Хотя порядок установки Linux проводился по свежим мануалам, и не сильно отличался от того, как я делал пару лет назад, при этом не имея описываемых проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение**

Предположение - часть плагинов xfce4 по прежнему требует библиотеки gtk2, но в зависимостях это по какой-то причине
пропало. Это и послужило причиной описываемой проблемы. Установка следующих пакетов проблему решила:

```
emerge x11-themes/gtk-engines 
emerge x11-themes/gtk-engines-flat
```

Более того, стало возможность задействовать "старые" темы.

Понимаю, вопрос мало тянет на "откровение", но, возможно, кому-то сэкономит 15-30 минут размышлений. Количество задаваемых вопросов в сети по
данной теме - тому подтверждение.

Теперь все нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]